# MYSQL using concat with case

Tags: mysql, case, concatenation

```
SELECT CONCAT(firstname," ",lastname," ",CASE dept_id
WHEN  '1'    THEN  'ITD'
WHEN  '4'    THEN  'FMAD'
WHEN  '6'    THEN  'GCSMD'
WHEN  '7'    THEN  'SSHED'
WHEN  '10'   THEN  'GPD'
ELSE  'Z_ISDC'
END AS ayam) as staffname
FROM ost_staff
```

The output that I want from `staffname` is "John Doe ITD" but
it doesn't work.

Comment: Please specify what it doesnt work

Comment: -1 "it doesn't work" is an absolutely horrible description of *any* problem.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a proper error message, explain a bit more what exactly does not work please.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this, your `CASE` is not formatted correct.

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(firstname," ",lastname," ",
CASE WHEN dept_id = '1' THEN 'ITD' 
     WHEN dept_id = '4' THEN 'FMAD' 
     WHEN dept_id = '6' THEN 'GCSMD' 
     WHEN dept_id = '7' THEN 'SSHED' 
     WHEN dept_id = '10' THEN 'GPD' ELSE 'Z_ISDC' END) 
as staffname 
FROM ost_staff
```

Also, you cant name your `CASE`, a simple `END` is needed for the `CASE`.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain himself ?

Comment: I was just gonna ask myself :)

Comment: Not the downvoter, but maybe it would have helped, if you explained what you did (removing the alias from the case, not formatting case).

Comment: I figured that pointing out that the CASE is wrong. But will put in explain.

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning for not using the `CASE <column> WHEN <expr>` as the OP has?

Comment: @lc, Just my way i guess, I find it more readable to write the syntax that way

Comment: @KayNelson how to concatenate THEN statement here with some dynamic parameter 
like - `** THEN 'ITD' + firstname + 'FMAD'`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `AS ayam` from the `CASE`'s `END`.

When you use the result of `CASE` clause as a parameter of `CONCAT`, you can't use alias.